# Average nested list document fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, average, nested-lists

I have a collection of documents that have a `field` of nested structure:

```
                        'field':[[x1,y1],...,[xN,yN]]
```

I am performing an aggregation by two fields and naively trying to return averaged "field" for each group:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
                               { $group: 
                                     {
                                         _id:{ a:"$field1", b:"$field2" },
                                         avgField:{$avg:"$field"}
                                     } 
                               }
                            ])
```

Averaging, obviously, doesn't work as I want it to. So the question is:
how can I return

```
                   avgField:[[<x1>,<y1>],...,[<xN>,<yN>]]
```

for each group, where <> is averaging operator?

---

Sample document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("551e77f803895f4329fec908"),
"time_added" : {
    "date" : "2015-04-03",
    "weekday" : 4,
    "hour" : 4
},
"item" : {


        "field" : [
            [
                [
                    1.1,
                    22.3
                ],
                [
                    1.5,
                    19.8
                ]
            ]

          },
          "item_id" : "161712665"
}
}
```

So I want to average "field" for documents that dated by same weekday and hour as I described above

Comment: Can you show a sample document with sample data?

Comment: Done. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Thanks @MaxPy, it indeed clarifies the problem a bit. Looks like you might need to `$unwind` each nested array level all the way through.

Comment: I'd be glad to be proven wrong, but I do not think this is possible with arrays of arbitrary length. You can unwind, but you don't have (AFAIK) the ability to `$group` on the correct criteria to compute the average, or to imbue the documents with that information using `$project`.